# Copy data from dataset to list Error

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

I'm getting some data from `Stored Procedure` to `DataSet` and then copying that data to a `List`. There are some `NULL` values in data and for that I'm checking with `DBNULL.Value`. But whenever it comes to a NULL value, it gives me error

> ERROR : Specified cast is not valid.

This is my class definition.

```
public class CustomClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ZoneId { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public int ExpCenId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public double Charges { get; set; }

}
```

This is how I'm copying data from DataSet to List.

```
objResult.lst.Add(new CustomClass()
{
  Code = dsLogin.Data[I]["Code"].ToString(),
  Id = (int)dsLogin.Data[I]["Id"],
  Name = dsLogin.Data[I]["Name"].ToString(),
  ShortName = dsLogin.Data[I]["ShortName"].ToString(),
  ZoneId = (int)dsLogin.Data[I]["ZoneId"],
  CityId = (int)(dsLogin.Data[I]["CityId"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : dsLogin.Data[I]["CityId"]),
  ExpCenId = (int)(dsLogin.Data[I]["ExpCenId"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : dsLogin.Data[I]["ExpCenId"]),
  CategoryId = (int)(dsLogin.Data[I]["CategoryId"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : dsLogin.Data[I]["CategoryId"]),
  Charges = (double)(dsLogin.Data[I]["Charges"] == DBNull.Value ? 0.0 : dsLogin.Data[I]["Charges"])
});
```

In case of `NULL`, When I check `dsLogin.Data[I]["CityId"]` in immediate window, it shows me **{ }** and when I check

```
(int)(dsLogin.Data[I]["CityId"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : dsLogin.Data[I]["CityId"])
```

It shows **0** but when I try to copy this in **CityId**, It throws Exception.

I'm stuck over here and don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any Kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `IsCityIdNull()` instead of `DBNull`. DataSet generates autmoatically null functions for all fields.

Or

Try `Convert.ToInt32` instead of (int).